# Mapping POCOs in "schema.tablename" format in EF 4.1 code first, using dotconnect for Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ef-code-first, code-first

I have this entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


}
```

I want this entity to mapped into Oracle an oracle 11g database as MySchema.MyEntity

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyEntity", "MySchema");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to add an entity ,and do SaveChanges, it completely ignores the schema part of the ToTable(), even if I add a  [Table("MySchema.MyEntity") ]    attribute to the class it is also ignored. Schema will always be the login name of the connnection string regardless of what I do.

```
        DbConnection con = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection(
      "User Id=system;Password=admin;Server=XE;Persist Security Info=true;");
```

The schema name is always what I set as UserId. It only changes if I write down explicitly that:

```
    con.ChangeDatabase("MySchema"); //this will only work if the database connection is open...
```

But I do now want to write this down...

How to make this work?

**EDIT:**

Oh man... Solution :

First : UPPERCASESCHEMANAMES!!!

Second: In the offical dotconnect example there is a line:

```
config.Workarounds.IgnoreSchemaName = true;
```

Delete it... (this will only work if you set the schema name for ALL your entities, otherwise a "dbo" schema will be used that does not exist in oracle... )

Comment: [Table("MyEntity", Schema = "MySchema")]
 
is also ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kori0129, your solution is correct. The corresponding blog article is here: http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html .

If you encounter any difficulties with the dotConnect for Oracle functionality, please contact us via http://www.devart.com/company/contact.html .

Answer (score 1):

I used the ConnectionString to get the SCHEMA

Here's my solution:

```
   public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private string oracleSchema;

        public MyContext()
            : base("OracleConnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

            oracleSchema = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString).UserID.ToUpper();

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}.{1}", oracleSchema, "CUSTOMER"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}.{1}", oracleSchema, "INVOICE"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}.{1}", oracleSchema, "PRODUCT"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}.{1}", oracleSchema, "CATEGORY"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}.{1}", oracleSchema, "ITEM"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().HasRequired(p => p.Customer);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(p => p.Invoice);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(p => p.Product);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.Categories)
                        .WithMany(x => x.Products)
                        .Map(x =>
                        {
                            x.ToTable("ASS_CATEGORY_PRODUCT", oracleSchema);
                            x.MapLeftKey("ID_CATEGORY");
                            x.MapRightKey("ID_PRODUCT");
                        });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.Products)
                        .WithMany(x => x.Categories)
                        .Map(x =>
                        {
                            x.ToTable("ASS_CATEGORY_PRODUCT", oracleSchema);
                            x.MapLeftKey("ID_PRODUCT");
                            x.MapRightKey("ID_CATEGORY");
                        });
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```